# Volley cancel request in arrayadapter with Android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-volley

I have a MainActivity Class file with listview  and ArrayAdapter class in the other file.

In the ArrayAdapter class I have a button in the listitem using Volley to update a record in a remote Rest Server.

I have read  about Cancel Request on Volley using:

```
@Override
protected void onStop () {
    super.onStop();
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(TAG);
    }
}
```

My doubt is: Do I need take care about cancel volley request in some android lifecycle event?
If yes, how do I do it into the arrayadapter class?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 ArrayList<ObjectQueue> lista = new ArrayList<ObjectQueue>();
 ListviewQueueAdapter lvA;
 ListView lv;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listmain);
        View v = (View) findViewById(R.id.emptymain);

        lv.setEmptyView(v);


        lvA = new ListviewQueueAdapter(MainActivity.this, lista);
        lv.setAdapter(lvA);
        lvA.setData(lista);

}
```

My arrayadapter class is something as:

```
public class ListviewQueueAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ObjectQueue>  implements Filterable {
    ArrayList<ObjectQueue> items; //working values
    ArrayList<ObjectQueue>  origitems; // data work
    private Activity context;

    RequestQueue reqQueue; //Volley request

    public ListviewQueueAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<ObjectQueue> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.singlerowqueue, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items=items;
    }

    public void add(ObjectQueue oq){
        this.items.add(oq);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ObjectQueue o = items.get(position);
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singlerowqueue, null);// e' preciso fazer o inflate pois a view nao ainda nao esta em activity alguma
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mbut_stat = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.but_status);
            ....
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
          holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.mbut_stat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                  b.setTitle("Mudar STATUS");
                  String[] types = {"Normal", "Urgente", "Pendente", "Atendido"};
                  b.setItems(types, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        update_fila(o, which + 1);
                    }

                });
                b.show();
            }

        });
        ......
        ......
        return vi;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        Button mbut_stat;
    }

    private void update_fila(final ObjectQueue ob, final int st) {
        reqQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        String url = Common.getServerURL() + "\"UpdateStatusFila\"";
        // constructs the POST body using the parameters
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
        ...
        FillSomeArray(ja);  
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonBody.put("_parameters", ja);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    dosomething()(; 
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        jr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(Common.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS,
                Common.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        reqQueue.add(jr);
    }
```

Comment: Hello man , it seems you know a bit about volley can you help me in this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100739/how-to-add-volley-image-request-in-an-arraylist/32100970#32100970

Comment: Ok, I put some code I use to get image into my array adapter in your question link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't 'need' to cancel the request in a lifecycle event. It's just that it would be good etiquette to save your user the bandwidth and battery life if the request is no longer relevant or useful to finish.

Where you put it is a design decision dependent on your particular needs, but you could add a method to your adapter:

```
public void onStop () {
  mRequestQueue.cancelAll(TAG);
}
```

and propagate the lifecycle call through from the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStop () {
  super.onStop();
  adapter.onStop();
}
```